# Initramfs after Kubuntu 16.04 installation - possibly partitioning error

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, kubuntu

I installed Kubuntu on my desktop, which had Windows 8.1 installed. The dual-boot options appear but when I try to boot into Kubuntu, I get stuck at an Initramfs terminal. Booting with Live USB, sudo fdisk -lu returns this:

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x730c4ee9

Device     Boot      Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1  *          2048     206847     204800   100M  7 HPFS/NTFS        /exFAT
/dev/sdb2           206848 1502089214 1501882367 716.2G  7 HPFS/NTFS        /exFAT
/dev/sdb3       1952602112 1953521663     919552   449M 27 Hidden NTFS     WinRE
/dev/sdb4       1502089215 1952602111  450512897 214.8G  5 Extended
/dev/sdb5       1502089216 1919082495  416993280 198.9G 83 Linux
/dev/sdb6       1919084544 1952602111   33517568    16G 82 Linux swap /     Solaris

Partition 4 does not start on physical sector boundary.
Partition table entries are not in disk order.
```

Can somebody help me, please?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed Windows 10 with UEFI](http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-10-with-uefi)

Answer (score 0):

I do just in gparted change flag boot as windows to linux.
too,in terminal linux type

`sudo update-grub`

and finally on grub both appear.

Comment: Could you clarify this a bit?  What do you mean by `change flag boot as windows to linux`?